# The difference between loss in model.compile() and model.add_loss() in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss

I am puzzled about what is difference between the add_loss and the traditional loss in model.compile()??

My code is like following:

```
from time import time
import numpy as np
import random
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer, InputSpec
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, GaussianNoise, Layer, Activation
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping


input_place = Input(shape=(128,))

e_layer1 = Dense(64,activation='relu')(input_place)
e_layer2 = Dense(32,activation='relu')(e_layer1)
hidden = Dense(16,activation='relu')(e_layer2)

d_layer1 = Dense(32,activation='relu')(hidden)
d_layer2 = Dense(64,activation='relu')(d_layer1)

output_place = Dense(128,activation='sigmoid')(d_layer2)

model = Model(inputs=input_place,outputs=output_place)

loss = K.mean(K.square(d_layer1 - e_layer2),axis = -1)

model.add_loss(loss)

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',
              loss=['mse'],
              metrics=['accuracy'])

input_data = np.random.randn(1,128)

model.fit(input_data,
          input_data,
          epochs=5)
```

As mentioned above, I made two loss function, one is a traditional MSE loss in model.compile() to compute the MSE_loss of input and output, and the other loss is also like a MSE loss, but it computes the middle_layers' MSE.
It can run, but I puzzled, with these two different ways to add loss, can my model know what they are clearly??

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your `Model` knows what they are, indeed.

The `loss` specified in the `model.compile` ensures that the `MSE` between `Y_Pred` and `Y_Actual` is reduced and the `model.add_loss` ensures that the difference between `d_layer1` and `e_layer2` is reduced.

It is equivalent to specifying two losses inside `model.compile` but the **basic difference** between the `loss` specified in `model.compile` and `model.add_loss` is that the loss specified in `model.compile` is restricted to the arguments, `y_true` and `y_pred` whereas in `model.add_loss`, we can specify the `Loss` with respect to any number of `Additional Tensors` used in our Project.

In other words, `model.add_loss` allows us to write much more `complex losses` that depend on many other `tensors`, but it has the inconvenience of being more dependent on the `model`, whereas the `standard loss functions (those used inside model.compile)` work with just any model.

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!